# When should you discard the in and/or out buffers of a SerialPort?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I am having small esoteric issues with my usage of the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class in my C# application. I currently have written a thread safe class on top of the `SerialPort` class and am having issues with `Read`s and `Write`s that occur with short times in between.

For instance I might `Write` a command and then `Read` a response. This behavior is within a `lock` statement, once the lock releases I might have a `Write` that occurs and then another `Write` `Read`. On my second `Read` I sometimes receive an empty `String`.

Now that is just to outline my issue, but trying to make a question that is answerable. I am simply looking for information about when you should use `DiscardOutBuffer` and `DiscardInBuffer`? **Basically are there any conventions on when to use these functions? Also, are the buffers ever discarded automatically in the underlying `SerialPort` implementation?**

I have to assume that my issues lie with the buffers. That either the in buffer is discard too early or that in buffer is not cleared in time.

Comment: Never is the 99.9% correct answer.  Technically they can be useful to implement a protocol reset to recover from a communication error.  But only if the protocol specifically demands it and somebody has thought through the consequences.  Having to use a *lock* is highly suspicious and a good a lead as any that your code is getting out of sync with the port traffic.  Add logging so you have a record of what happened.

Comment: Assuming that the device on the other end is not failing and that this is not high speed (> 1Mbps) you shouldn't have issues.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you explain more about why using a `lock` is suspicious? // The SerialPort `Read` and `Write` methods are not thread safe, I `lock` over them so that two separate `Task`s do not try to `Read` or `Write` to the port while another currently is.

Comment: It is suspicious because it is so easy to get wrong.  Which by the sound you did, you cannot allow a thread to call Read when another thread's Write is still waiting for the response.

Comment: I still don't think I follow. I might for instance `lock(myObj) { Write(msg); String resp = ReadLine(); }`. Another thread trying to execute `lock(myObj) { Write(msg); }` cannot possibly interleave its write with the firsts read-write? It will be blocked until the first threads read-write has completed, then the lock will be released and the second thread can enter.